# should I put the reference number after the dot or after a space?

Tags: style, publishing, technical-writing

I am writing my thesis. and I need to know the correct way of putting the reference.

for example:

> this is a sentence taken from someone [2].
>
> this is a sentence taken from someone[2].
>
> this is a sentence taken from someone. [2]
>
> this is a sentence taken from someone.[2]

as you see in the four sentences about, there are differences in the space place and the dot place, which one of the is correct? (or maybe all wrong? )

Answer (score 1):

The first is most often seen. Most journals have their own specifications for citations, but that one is very common. Also note you don't always have to place them at the end of a sentence. See [here](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0143047) for examples.